# aSmack - Packet to XML using Packet Listener outputs nullable elements

Tags: android, xmpp, listener, smack, asmack

I'm using aSmack in my Android app to communicate with my XMPP server, and I turned on the debug for Smack so I could see all the XML's coming/going. 
My problem here is that I am using a PacketListener to get the server response for the package that I sent, but when I call the toXML() method of the Packet I got an weird output. 
Classes and more details below.

My server has the XEP-0136 implementation and since aSmack doesn't have the code for it yet I am making the IQ packet and sending it, and this is working as expected, as you can see below my XML Packet, as designed in the XEP-0136, retrieving list of collections( http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#manage-list )

**Xml package sent to the server**

```
06-13 14:11:21.769: D/SMACK(3018): 02:11:21 PM SENT (1079273464): 
<iq id="john@company.com/Smack/Conversations" type="get">
  <list with="john@company.com" xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive">
    <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
      <max>30</max>
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```

To create this XML I got the XML Schema files as designed in the XEP-0136, and with the help of the SimpleXML lib I mapped all the elements and this is the code I am using to create and send the package:

**XMPPService.java**

```
private static final int MAX_LIST = 30;

public void getConversations(String email, BaseActivity activity)
{
    if (isAuthenticated())
    {
        String packetId = connection.getUser() + "/Conversations";
        Set set = new Set();
        set.setMax(MAX_LIST);

        List list = new List();
        list.setWith(email);
        list.setSet(set);

        final IQ iq = new IQ();
        iq.setList(list);
        iq.setType(IQType.get);
        iq.setId(packetId);

        PacketIDFilter filter = new PacketIDFilter(packetId);
        connection.addPacketListener(new ChatListListener(activity), filter);
        sendPacket(iq);
    }
}

public void sendPacket(IQ iq)
{
    if (isAuthenticated())
    {
        connection.sendPacket(new IQPacket(iq));
    }
}
```

**IQPacket.java**

```
public class IQPacket extends Packet {

 private IQ iq;

 public IQPacket(IQ iq)
 {
    this.iq = iq;
 }

 public IQPacket(Packet packet, IQ iq)
 {
    super(packet);
    this.iq = iq;
 }

 @Override
 public String toXML()
 {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    try
    {
        serializer.write(iq, writer);
        return writer.getBuffer().toString();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("COMPANY", "Error serializing xml", e);
    }
    return null;
 }

}
```

As I said, this part works, my problem is for the Listener, when I call the toXML() method for the package received, I can't get the important information about the chats, but the Smack debugging output prints to me all the information that I'm expecting as you can see below:

**Smack Debug for received XML**

```
06-13 14:11:21.989: D/SMACK(3018): 02:11:21 PM RCV  (1079273464): 
<iq type="result" id="john@company.com/Smack/Conversations" to="john@company.com/Smack">
  <list xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive">
    <chat with="anotheruser@company.com" start="2013-06-10T13:19:25.000Z"/>
    <chat with="yetanotheruser@company.com" start="2013-06-10T13:36:50.876Z"/>
    <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
      <first index="0">2</first>
      <last>3</last>
      <count>9</count>
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```

Also this XML is the expected answer since I have all those elements mapped as JavaBeans, but this is what I get when I receive the Packet on my ChatListener and call the toXML() method:

```
06-13 14:11:22.009: I/System.out(3018): 
<iq id="john@company.com/Smack/Conversations" to="john@company.com/Smack" type="result">nullnullnullnullnullnull2nullnull3nullnull9nullnull</iq>
```

**ChatListListener.java**

```
public class ChatListListener implements PacketListener {

 private BaseActivity activity;

 public ChatListListener(BaseActivity activity)
 {
    this.activity = activity;
 }

 @Override
 public void processPacket(Packet packet)
 {
    activity.notifyPacketReceived();
    System.out.println(packet.toXML());
 }
}
```

The **Packet** is from org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet, so it's the default Packet from the aSmack lib.

So my question is, what am I doing different of the Smack debugger? I looked its code and for what I saw it also calls the toXML() method from the packet and add a ReceiveListener.
My idea here is after I call the toXML() I can use SimpleXML to transform it into my IQ.java that I mapped and start using its information.

**EDIT**

Adding more information. So after looking up the Smack code and how it handles the package received, I figure out that maybe I should use an IQProvider.
So I registered my IQProvider

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("list", "urn:xmpp:archive", new ListIQProvider());
```

And after that I put a breakpoint on the method **parseIQ(XmlPullParser arg0)** of my IQProvider, and the package is actually being sent to my provider, but still it has all those null elements. I'm kind lost right now because I need this to keep working, I will keep investigating the Smack source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lot of research and looking Smack sources, I found out the solution.
The steps are, add IQProvider, add a PacketListener for your packet, send the packet. Wait for the packet on your IQProvider, parse it, and get your response on your Listener.

So the **addIQProvider** and **addPacketListener** were both right, the thing is, I need to do the complete parse of the XML on my ListIQProvider, it sounds simple but took me some time to figure that out.

```
public class ListIQProvider implements IQProvider {

 public ListIQProvider()
 {
 }

 @Override
 public IQ parseIQ(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception
 {
    Logger.d(String.format("Received iq packet, namespace[%s], name[%s]", parser.getNamespace(), parser.getName()));
    ListIQ iq = new ListIQ();
    ListIQ.Set set = new Set();
    boolean done = false;

    String with = "", start = "";
    while (!done)
    {
        int eventType = parser.next();
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
        {
            if (parser.getName().equals("chat"))
            {
                with = parser.getAttributeValue("", "with");
                start = parser.getAttributeValue("", "start");
                iq.addChat(new Chat(with, start));
            }
            else if (parser.getName().equals("first"))
            {
                int index = parseInt(parser.getAttributeValue("", "index"));
                set.setIndexAtt(index);
                int first = parseInt(parser.nextText());
                set.setFirst(first);
            }
            else if (parser.getName().equals("last"))
            {
                int last = parseInt(parser.nextText());
                set.setLast(last);
            }
            else if (parser.getName().equals("count"))
            {
                int count = parseInt(parser.nextText());
                set.setCount(count);
            }
        }
        else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
        {
            if (parser.getName().equals("list"))
            {
                iq.setSet(set);
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return iq;
 }

 private int parseInt(String integer)
 {
    return Integer.parseInt((integer != null ? integer : "0"));
 }
}
```

After that, all I had to do on my **ChatListListener** was casting the **Packet** to my **ListIQ** class. That's it.
The thing here is, the **Packet** being received on my **ChatListListener** is the same **Packet** that is being returned on the parseIQ method on my **ListIQProvider**.
So in this question/answer we have almost everything you need for XEP-0136, or at least start using it.
Since I didn't found any good and simple source on the web to help me, I'm sharing mine here. Below it's the ListIQ class:

```
public class ListIQ extends IQ {

 private List<Chat> chats;

 private Set set;

 public ListIQ()
 {
    this.chats = new ArrayList<ListIQ.Chat>();
 }

 public Set getSet()
 {
    return set;
 }

 public void setSet(Set set)
 {
    this.set = set;
 }

 public void addChat(Chat chat)
 {
    chats.add(chat);
 }

 public List<Chat> getChats()
 {
    return chats;
 }

 @Override
 public String getChildElementXML()
 {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<list xmlns=\"urn:xmpp:archive\">");
    for (Chat chat : chats)
    {
        builder.append(chat.toXml());
    }
    builder.append(set.toXml());
    builder.append("</list>");
    return builder.toString();
 }

 public static class Chat {
    private String with;
    private String start;

    public Chat()
    {
    }

    public Chat(String with, String start)
    {
        this.with = with;
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String getWith()
    {
        return with;
    }

    public void setWith(String with)
    {
        this.with = with;
    }

    public String getStart()
    {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(String start)
    {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String toXml()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<chat with=\"");
        builder.append(with).append("\"");
        builder.append(" start=\"");
        builder.append(start);
        builder.append("\"/>");
        return builder.toString();
    }

 }

 public static class Set {
    private int last;
    private int count;
    private int indexAtt;
    private int first;

    public Set()
    {
    }

    public int getLast()
    {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(int last)
    {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getIndexAtt()
    {
        return indexAtt;
    }

    public void setIndexAtt(int indexAtt)
    {
        this.indexAtt = indexAtt;
    }

    public int getFirst()
    {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(int first)
    {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public String toXml()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<set xmlns=\"http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm\">");
        builder.append("<first index=\"").append(indexAtt).append("\">").append(first).append("</first>");
        builder.append("<last>").append(last).append("</last>");
        builder.append("<count>").append(count).append("</count>");
        builder.append("</set>");
        return builder.toString();
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: can you answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566411/how-to-parse-a-customiq-in-asmack I also face the same issue

Comment: Thanks for the complete source, it's exactly what I needed. Is this why people prefer JSON now or is this just terrible design?

Comment: No problem. Actually the XEP's have a good design, it's just troublesome to implement it yourself. I don't think JSON would fit the XMPP requirements, it makes more sense to use XML I guess, and also the protocol is older then JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i also had the same problem and I can tell that this code works I would just change the way you build the query for the list to the server. (At least on my server)

```
final IQ iq = new IQ()
    {

        @Override public String getChildElementXML()
        {

            return "<list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'/>";

        }
    };

    iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);

    PacketTypeFilter filter = new PacketTypeFilter(Packet.class);


    connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener()
    {
        @Override public void processPacket(Packet packet)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, packet.toXML());
        }
    }, filter);

    connection.sendPacket(iq);
```

as you said before it seems pretty easy but the documentation is not really clear about how to build the IQ object. I hope it helps.

Comment: But you will still not able to parse the response. You are just making it possible to send a request to retrieve chats.

Comment: Of course not, to process the answer you need to register a provider as you did. I just tried to make your post a little bit better, still your code is the important part thus I have developed the classes that extend from IQProvider to parse a Chat (and a Message) quite different. Still I gave you +1 because your post helped me out a lot.

Comment: Hey i tried but i get error 503 service not available.            <iq id="hsWL2-4" to="test@XX.XX.XX.XX" from="test@XX.XX.XX.XX" type="error"><error code="503" type="CANCEL">
<service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>

Comment: @Hardik , it sound like the server is not working or the message archive is not available?