# How to parse a CustomIQ in ASMACK

Tags: android, asmack

I am using ASMACK library fo my application. I received the following IQ from my server.

```
<iq id='bind_2' type='result'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'><jid username='xx' fullname='yy'>xx@aa.bb.cc.dd/Resource</jid></bind></iq>
```

For parsing this IQ, I added the IQProvider while setting **XmppConnection** configuration by using **ProviderManager** class as

```
ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("bind",
                        "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind",
                        new CustomIQProvider());
```

And my **CustomIQProvider** class is

```
public class CustomIQProvider implements IQProvider {
    public static final String NAME_SPACE = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind";

    @Override
    public IQ parseIQ(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception {

        Log.i("My_TAG", "inside LivBindIQ");
        CustomIQ bindIQ = new CustomIQ();
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Parser not in proper position, or bad XML.");
        }
        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
            int eventType = parser.next();
            if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    && ("entry".equals(parser.getName()))) {
                eventType = parser.next();
                String name = parser.nextText();
                eventType = parser.next();
                String value = parser.nextText();
            }
            else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                done = true;
            }
        }

        return bindIQ;

    }

}
```

And my **CustomIQ** class is,

```
public class CustomIQ extends IQ {

    @Override
    public String getChildElementXML() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    }
```

Now I am confused about, how the `CustomIQProvider` class be executed.. I didn't get any log from `CustomIQProvider` class. Whether my steps are correct otherwise I need to do any steps for calling my `CustomIQProvider` class

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's a provider already register for this namespace?
Perhaps you need to do the complete and correct parse of the XML on your IQProvider, and also your CustomIQ need to implement the correct output of the xml.
You are checking for a  tag, where clearly it doesn't exist, so this parser will never work.
Assuming this is the tag you want to parse

```
<jid username='xx' fullname='yy'>xx@aa.bb.cc.dd/Resource</jid>
```

I didn't tested but this should work, your parseIQ method should look like this

```
public IQ parseIQ(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception {
  CustomIQ bindIQ = new CustomIQ();
  while (!done) {
    int eventType = parser.next();
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        if (parser.getName().equals("jid")) {
            String username = parser.getAttributeValue("", "username");
            String fullname = parser.getAttributeValue("", "fullname");
            String jidValue = parser.nextText();

            bindIQ.setUsername(username);
            bindIQ.setFullname(fullname);
            bindIQ.setFullJid(jidValue);
        }
    }
    else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getName().equals("jid")) {
            done = true;
        }
    }
  }
  return bindIQ;
}
```

And your CustomIQ class:

```
public class CustomIQ extends IQ {

  private String username;
  private String fullName;
  private String fullJid;

  public CustomIQ() {

  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
      this.username = username;
  }

  public void setFullname(String fullName) {
      this.fullName = fullName;
  }

  public void setFullJid(String fullJid) {
      this.fullJid = fullJid;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
      return this.username;
  }

  public String getFullname() {
      return this.fullName;
  }

  public String getFullJid() {
      return this.fullJid;
  }

  @Override
  public String getChildElementXML() {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("<bind xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind\"><jid username=\"");
      builder.append(username).append("\"");
      builder.append(" fullname=\"");
      builder.append(fullName).append("\"");
      builder.append(">");
      builder.append(fullJid);
      builder.append("</jid>");
      builder.append("</bind>");
      return builder.toString();
  }

}
```

Comment: ya I already used this step its working fine but I need to use through ProviderManager.. thanks for your response

Comment: According to what you posted your code is incomplete my friend. did you tried with both classes that I posted? Also did you checked if any class from aSmack is already registering a provider for this namespace?